# I want to use full-text search in Japanese with Apache Ignite

Tags: lucene, ignite, kuromoji

https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/2fbbb676386515ea881e4e61f08864d6bc93225a/modules/indexing/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/internal/processors/query/h2/opt/GridLuceneIndex.java#L115

It looks like Standard Analyzer is being used for now.
Are there any plans to allow the Lucene analyzer to be switched in the config file in the future?

Thanks.

Comment: I think that you should recur to Google or Bing for this kind of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 2020, text indexing in Apache Ignite is not under active development. I think it would make more sense to have your own Lucene index on the side.